# OpenNI Kinect Choosing Subjects for Tracking

Tags: kinect, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to modify the openni_kinect code so that you can give a set of coordinates and it will search for people to track between those coordinates? Also, is it possible to modify it so that if something that is not a person is being tracked, you can tell it to stop tracking it? It seems as though the program currently just tracks what it wants to.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10919/openni-kinect-choosing-subjects-for-tracking/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The features you talk about are not supported by the openni_kinect stack. It sounds more like an application you want to build using the openni_kinect driver.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0